# Slick2D/LWJGL crashes jvm when loading fonts (both TrueTypeFont and UnicodeFont)

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

OS: Windows 10

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slick2d</groupId>
  <artifactId>slick2d-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

LWJGL natives: 2.9.3

The code I'm using is:

```
public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
  try {
    java.awt.Font temp = java.awt.Font.createFont(java.awt.Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("resources/5x5_pixel.ttf"));
    temp = temp.deriveFont(java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 5);
    // Crashes here:
    new TrueTypeFont(temp, false);
    // and here:
    new UnicodeFont(temp);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

It crashes without throwing an exception, so I'm unsure how to debug this.  Everything renders/runs fine without the fonts, and I've tested multiple fonts all seem to crash the same way.  (Note, it throws a different error if the font is missing, so I've looked at that too).

Thanks!

Comment: Could you check whether this code causes a crash as well? Example:

`public static Font playerNameFont = new Font("playerName", Font.BOLD, 13);`

`public static TrueTypeFont playerName = new TrueTypeFont(playerNameFont,false);`

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad It crashes on the line `TrueTypeFont playerName = new TrueTypeFont(playerNameFont,false);`.  The initial java.awt.font loads, I can print it out and I get `java.awt.Font[family=Dialog,name=playerName,style=bold,size=13]`.  And actually, it works on another windows 10 computer (same code/resources/natives), so I'm not sure how to proceed...

Comment: This is really weird. For me your code works fine. (Except for the fact that I used a different .ttf) Is it possible that you are encountering an OutOfMemoryError? Usually Java does not print an exception then. See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343746/java-vm-suddenly-exiting-without-apparent-reason

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @eric_the_animal Unfortunately, I did not... and it turns out that I haven't been able to reproduce it on another windows 10 machine.